# Vue.js Object is returning but i want to open that Object

Tags: html, vue.js

This is my code to get the Object which is returning but I cannot open that object I want to open and see whats in it

```
            var connections = [];
         $.each(instance.getAllConnections(), function (idx, connection) {
          connections.push({
              connectionId: connection.id,
              pageSourceId: connection.sourceId,
              pageTargetId: connection.targetId,
              anchors: $.map(connection.endpoints, function(endpoint) {

            return [[endpoint.anchor.x, 
            endpoint.anchor.y, 
            endpoint.anchor.getOrientation()[0], 
            endpoint.anchor.getOrientation()[1],
            endpoint.anchor.offsets[0],
            endpoint.anchor.offsets[1]
        ]];
  })

          });
        console.log(util.inspect(connections.endpoints));


          });
          // console.log(connections);
        console.log(util.inspect(connections));
```

This is what I am getting in the Object

[image: This is mine Console Object]

Comment: Hi Asad - just to be clear, you want to display something more informative in your console.log output than just ```anchors: [object] [object]``` ?

Comment: This is caused by util.inspect default depth of 2, you can still access to anchors objects

Comment: I would add that `console.debug(connections)` would be much more appropriate if you problem is to inspect connections array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Object by doing this

```
             var connections = [];
     $.each(instance.getAllConnections(), function (idx, connection) {
      connections.push({
          connectionId: connection.id,
          pageSourceId: connection.sourceId,
          pageTargetId: connection.targetId,
          arrowendpoint1:connection.endpoints[0].anchor.x,
          arrowendpoint2:connection.endpoints[0].anchor.y, 
          arrownendpoint3:connection.endpoints[1].anchor.x,
          arrownendpoint4:connection.endpoints[1].anchor.y,


      //     anchors: $.map(connection.endpoints, function(endpoint) {

      //   return [[endpoint.anchor.x, 
      //   endpoint.anchor.y, 
      //   endpoint.anchor.getOrientation()[0], 
      //   endpoint.anchor.getOrientation()[1],
      //   endpoint.anchor.offsets[0],
      //   endpoint.anchor.offsets[1]
      //     ]];
      // })
    });
});
    console.log(util.inspect(connections));
```